# NGINX HTTP/3 phpMyAdmin 5.1.1 epoll_ctl(1, 16) failed (17: File exists)

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, http3

I am getting this log and Interner Server Error 500 message, when using phpMyAdmin 5.1.1 and HTTP/3 enabled on NGINX Server. With HTTP/2 protocol works well.

```
2021/11/04 18:11:27 [alert] 21777#21777: *259 epoll_ctl(1, 16) failed (17: File exists), client: 37.234.***.***, server: *******, request: "POST /phpadmin/index.php?route=/config/get HTTP/3", host: "*******"
```

EDIT:
I installed a new nginx server with Cloudflare's http3. I used this script:
https://github.com/angristan/nginx-autoinstall/blob/master/nginx-autoinstall.sh

I installed Php 7.4 fastCgi and downloaded and unpacked Phpmyadmin 5.1.1.

I got these nginx error log after started up nginx and logging in to phpmyadmin:

```
2021/11/04 18:54:32 [notice] 23537#23537: signal process started
2021/11/04 18:54:46 [alert] 23539#23539: *288 epoll_ctl(1, 16) failed (17: File exists), client: 37.234.122.188, server: harisnyauzlet.hu, request: "POST /phpadmin/index.php?route=/ HTTP/3", host: "harisnyauzlet.hu"
2021/11/04 18:55:10 [alert] 23539#23539: *288 epoll_ctl(1, 16) failed (17: File exists), client: 37.234.122.188, server: harisnyauzlet.hu, request: "POST /phpadmin/index.php?route=/ HTTP/3", host: "harisnyauzlet.hu"
2021/11/04 20:14:00 [crit] 23539#23539: *307 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC) while SSL handshaking, client: 128.1.248.26, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2021/11/04 21:00:08 [crit] 23539#23539: *314 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC) while SSL handshaking, client: 193.118.53.202, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2021/11/05 01:07:19 [crit] 23539#23539: *354 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC) while SSL handshaking, client: 128.14.134.134, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Comment: Do other PHP pages work over HTTP/3? Do static HTML pages work?

Comment: Yes, static HTML pages and PHP pages work over HTTP/3.  Over HTTP/2 I am got these error messages: The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).
 The $cfg['TempDir'] (/var/www/*****/phpmyadmin/tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error code, but I notice that the page it's trying to load is `index.php?route=/config/get` which seems odd, does that same message happen if you are trying to load `https://example.com/phpadmin/` directly? Do you get to the login page or does it fail before you even reach that part?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get the login page, but I can't logging in to Phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug by Cloudflare (Angristan use their quiche/nginx patch). You have this error when you use POST with a body.

But, the Cloudflare team doesn’t use POST in their system, so it is not a priority for them.

> Clouflare Team : It's definitely something we should fix at some point, though we don't really have an estimate right now as it's not very high priority (we don't use this option ourselves in production). Would definitely welcome patches though, so I'll leave this ticket open if anyone wants to work on this before we get to it.

This was from one year ago. [More about the issue](https://giters.com/cloudflare/quiche/issues/640).